# what is the difference between "that shirt looks good on you" & "you look good in that shirt"?

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning

I often hear people say "you look good in that shirt"

But recently, I have heard a native speaker say  "**that shirt looks good on you**".

So:
what is the difference between **"that shirt looks good on you**" & "**you look good in that shirt**"?

Answer (score 4):

There's no real difference, but in the first example the emphasis is a bit more on the "shirt" (the shirt looks good) and in the second one on "you" (you look good).